# Maintaining User Login State Even After App Uninstallation on Android, Similar to iOS Keychain

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, mobile-application

I've been wondering if there's an effective way to keep the user logged in even after uninstalling an application on Android, similar to how iOS stores login credentials in its Keychain. I've noticed that some iOS applications have this feature, but it doesn't seem to be as common on Android.

I've examined several iOS apps that are able to preserve the login state even after the app is reinstalled, but I haven't found the same behavior on Android. I'm curious if this could be due to operating system limitations or security considerations.

I would like to know if anyone has experience with such an implementation on Android and if there are any known solutions to achieve this goal.

I've seen some users mention that Firebase Auth seems to exhibit this behavior. However, upon my attempts to recreate the scenario – enabling user data backup in the Android app's manifest, uninstalling the app, and then reinstalling it the user was no longer logged in.

Has anyone successfully implemented this feature on Android or has more information about potential limitations or security considerations that might be involved?

Thank you very much in advance for any input or shared experiences!